# How to create boolean field that check the current user in odoo V11?

Tags: odoo-11

I'm working on **Employee directory** module in **Odoo 11** and I want to create a **compute** **field** that check for each employee if it's **related user** is equivalent to the **current user** (**logged user**).
I create the compute function but it allways return false.

**Python code :**

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'User', related='resource_id.user_id')
current_user = fields.Boolean('is current user ?', compute='_get_current_user')

@api.depends('user_id')
def _get_current_user(self):
    for e in self:
        e.current_user = (self.env.user.id == e.user_id)
```

**Any help please ?**

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code.

```
user_id = fields.Many2one('res.users', 'User', related='resource_id.user_id')
current_user = fields.Boolean('is current user ?', compute='_get_current_user')

@api.depends('user_id')
def _get_current_user(self):
for e in self:
    e.current_user = (True if e.env.user.id == e.user_id.id else False)
```